# Комментарии в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Можно ли в ассемблере закомментировать сразу несколько строк, т.е. без установки ';' в начале каждой строки?

Answer (score 8):

В действительности, синтаксис комментариев сильно зависит от используемого ассемблера. Например, используя `GNU as`, можно пользоваться комментариями в стиле языка C, т.е. заключать текст комментария в `/* */`.

Подробнее см., например, в [Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler#Multi-line_comments).

А вот при использовании `nasm` можно выкрутиться так:

```
%ifdef COMMENT
комментируемый код
%endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Для многострочных комментариев общего соглашения (`IDEAL`) не существует, однако многие ассемблеры, поддерживающие `MASM mode`, поддерживают и масмовскую директиву `COMMENT`:

> Comments: A semicolon starts a
> comment. A comment may follow a
> statement or it may be on a separate
> line. Multiple- line comments can be
> written by using the COMMENT
> directive. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> COMMENT delimiter {comment}
> comment
> ...
> delimiter { comment }
> ```
>
> where delimiter is any non-blank
> character not appearing in comment.
> The curly brackets indicate an item
> that is optional. e.g.,
>
> ```
> COMMENT *
> This program finds
> the maximum element in a byte array
> *
> ```

Comment: Странно, всё правильно и куча минусов.

Comment: Вот они, неуловимые мстители :-)
[*](http://hashcode.ru/users/5040/asen/reputation/)
[*](http://hashcode.ru/users/3545/alexwindhope/reputation/)

Answer (score 0):

Не все компиляторы ассемблера, к сожалению, поддерживает многострочные комментарии. Только однострочные. Разработчикам просто казалось глупым комментировать код  такого низкоуровневого языка. Это же вам мне C#, где одна строчка кода может занимать более 10 ассемблерных команд.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096374/multiple-line-comments-in-assembly][1]?

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096374/multiple-line-comments-in-assembly

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, в большинстве компиляторов это не работает.

Comment: @Asen Да понятно, что это зависит от выбранного ассемблера. Тем не менее, исходный вопрос был сформулирован как *"Можно ли ...",* а значит ответ *"Нет, нельзя"* некорректен.

Comment: @Котик, да, спасибо)

Comment: Спасибо Котик, Вы мне помогли. Данный способ мне подошел.
 COMMENT @
 Комментируемый текст
 Еще комментируемый текст
 @